# Search A Variable in Specific Column in BASH with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have LOG_FILE like below:

```
LOG|Server301|2015|05|12|00|58|35|572617|0|COMP|002.01.003.00|DSOHMSN2ViewCallback.cpp|142|CALLBACK:DSOHMSN2ViewCallback::FLIPBypassOn Changed SN=2 old value =2 new value =1
LOG|Client2|2015|05|12|00|58|35|593088|0|COMP|002.01.003.00|AMSN.cpp|12577|CALLBACK:OHMOAM::ohmSN2ViewChange, Old FLIPBypassOnMT
LOG|Server302|2015|05|12|00|58|35|593116|0|COMP|002.01.003.00|AMSN.cpp|12590|CALLBACK:OHMOAM::ohmSN4ViewChange, New FLIPBypassOnMT
LOG|Server301|2015|05|12|00|58|35|593302|0|COMP|002.01.003.00|AMSN.cpp|12577|CALLBACK:OHMOAM::ohmSN3ViewChange, Old disableFLIPBypassOnMT
LOG|Client1|2015|05|12|00|58|35|593324|0|COMP|002.01.003.00|AMSN.cpp|12590|CALLBACK:OHMOAM::ohmSN2ViewChange, New disableFLIPBypassOnMT
```

I just want to print line no which have

- word `Server` at 2nd column
- word `CALLBACK` at 15th column
- variable `$parameter_name` at 15th column

I executed the below command:

```
parameter_name="FLIPBypassOnMT"
$(awk -v var="$parameter_name" -F'|' '$2 ~ /Server/ && $15 ~ /CALLBACK/  && index($15,var) { print NR}' $LOG_FILE 2>/dev/null | tail -1)
```

But Not getting the line no.
I am using sun4-solaris.
please help me out.
N.B:

```
$(awk -v var="$parameter_name" -F'|' '$2 ~ /Server/ && $15 ~ /CALLBACK/ { print NR}' $LOG_FILE 2>/dev/null | tail -1)
```

is running fine.
but need all the three criteria.

Comment: Please read the [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I messed up. now it's fine.

Comment: Does `awk '$2 ~ /Server/ && $15 ~ /CALLBACK/'` command work fine?

Comment: What output do you expect on standard error and why are you discarding it? Usually you want to know why when something fails.

Comment: Usually `awk '{... print x}' | tail -n 1` can usefully be refactored to `awk '{... last=x} END {print last}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks both of you @tripleee and @bkmoney
I have used the below command and works fine:

```
$(nawk -v var="$parameter_name" -F'|' '$2 ~ /Server/ && $15 ~ /CALLBACK/  && $15 ~ var { print NR}' $LOG_FILE 2>/dev/null | tail -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$(awk -v var="$parameter_name" -F'|' '$2 ~ /Server/ && $15 ~ /CALLBACK/  && $15 ~ var { print NR}' $LOG_FILE 2>/dev/null | tail -1)
```

I'm not sure why you used the index function when you can use the `~` regex operator again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the problem lies elsewhere.

If

```
awk blah blah
```

prints `23` then

```
$(awk blah blah)
```

will attempt to execute `23` as a shell command (and usually fail).  Remove the  process substitution at least while  debugging this problem.

Tangentially,  some Sun systems have a very  limited Awk, but I guess that's not the problem here. Still, you might want to google for "Solaris XPG4 Awk".